# jobs / wc: getting weird return values

Tags: gnu, wc, jobs

I can't make sense of these return values.

When I run `jobs -s | wc -l`, I get different results depending on what directory I'm in.

If I'm in the directory that I returned to after suspending the job, I get the correct answer.

If I'm in any other directory, I get the correct answer + 1.

See screenshot:

[image]

I also ran `jobs -s | > test.txt` and got a single line document, then ran `wc -l < test.txt` and got the right output.

Any idea what's causing this? As you can see, it's messing up my background jobs indicator in my shell prompt (right side, blue).

Any suggestions on how to fix this function would be greatly appreciated:

```
#tells us how many jobs are in the background  
function jobs_status() {
  count=$(jobs -s | wc -l)
  if [[ $count -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "$bg_jobs$split$fg_text $count $fg_jobs"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are two lines in later case, one being shown, one not because it is being shown in a subshell with a trailing newline that is being counted. I have checked `zsh` and `bash`, this behavior exists in `zsh`, `bash` behaves similarly with different formatting.

Take a look at the following ASCII dump from `zsh`:

```
/tmp/test% jobs
[1]  + running    tail -f /var/log/syslog

/tmp/test% jobs | wc -l
1

/tmp/test% jobs | od -c
0000000   [   1   ]           +       r   u   n   n   i   n   g        
0000020           t   a   i   l       -   f       /   v   a   r   /   l
0000040   o   g   /   s   y   s   l   o   g  \n
0000052

/tmp/test% cd ..

/tmp% jobs | wc -l
2

/tmp% jobs | od -c
0000000   [   1   ]           +       r   u   n   n   i   n   g        
0000020           t   a   i   l       -   f       /   v   a   r   /   l
0000040   o   g   /   s   y   s   l   o   g  \n   (   p   w   d       n
0000060   o   w   :       /   t   m   p   )  \n
0000072
```

It seems shell is keeping track of the current working directory, look at `( p   w   d       n
0000060   o   w   :       /   t   m   p )`, the parentheses indicate subshell.

Here is the relevant source code of `zsh`, `jobs.c`:

```
/* print "(pwd now: foo)" messages: with (lng & 4) we are printing
 * the directory where the job is running, otherwise the current directory
 */

    if ((lng & 4) || (interact && job == thisjob &&
                      jn->pwd && strcmp(jn->pwd, pwd))) {
        doneprint = 1;
        fprintf(fout, "(pwd %s: ", (lng & 4) ? "" : "now");
        fprintdir(((lng & 4) && jn->pwd) ? jn->pwd : pwd, fout);
        fprintf(fout, ")\n");
        fflush(fout);
    }
```

While `bash` has:

```
      if (strcmp (temp, jobs[job_index]->wd) != 0)
        fprintf (stream,
          _("  (wd: %s)"), polite_directory_format (jobs[job_index]->wd));
```

To get what you want you can run `jobs` in a subshell:

```
( jobs ) | wc -l
```

Comment: Very interesting. Two questions: 1) Why isn't that line of text visible? 2) Any idea how I can fix the function? (edited into original post). Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaD check my edits

Comment: Thanks. Answer accepted. Would you mind explaining why the line is invisible, and why running in a subshell fixes the problem?